# How to mask missed calls to read in Android?

Tags: android, calllog

I am working to an Android app that displays the missed calls using:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
    CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
    CallLog.Calls._ID
};

String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1" ;         
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(
    CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    where,
    null,
    null
 );
c.moveToFirst();    
if (c.getCount() > 0) newCountersObj.missedCallCounter = c.getCount();
```

After checking the missed calls in my android listview I want to mark them as read in android DB. How can I do that?

**Question update** with the following link:

[clear missed calls error in android.database.SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564376/clear-missed-calls-error-in-android-database-sqlite)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By setting `is_read` flag to true. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#IS_READ

Example (from [ClearMissedCallsService](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Phone/+/master/src/com/android/phone/ClearMissedCallsService.java)):

```
    // Clear the list of new missed calls.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Calls.NEW, 0);
    values.put(Calls.IS_READ, 1);
    StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
    where.append(Calls.NEW);
    where.append(" = 1 AND ");
    where.append(Calls.TYPE);
    where.append(" = ?");
    context.getContentResolver().update(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, where.toString(),
            new String[]{ Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE) });
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. Can you five me an example based on the code I post?

Comment: I have the following error: android.database.sqlite.SWLiteException: no such column; is_read, while compiling: UPDATE logs SET is_read=?, new=? WHERE (new=1 and type=?)

Comment: can you help? I m getting a log saying that logtype = 100 or 500?

Comment: Please update your question, and post your latest code and the exception stack.

Comment: I've posted a new question. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564376/clear-missed-calls-error-in-android-database-sqlite