# clear missed calls error in android.database.SQLite

Tags: android, calllog

I have the following code for clear missed logs:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Calls.NEW, 0);
        values.put(Calls.IS_READ, 1);
        StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
        where.append(Calls.NEW);
        where.append(" = 1 AND ");
        where.append(Calls.TYPE);
        where.append(" = ?");

        context.getContentResolver().update(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, where.toString(),
                new String[]{ Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE) });
```

When running this code I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: is_read, while compiling UPDATE logs SET is_read=?, new=? WHERE (new = 1 AND type = ?) AND (logtype = 100 or logtype = 500)
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Calls.IS_READ`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#IS_READ) was introduced in API level 14.

You should only set this value if the device API is greater or equal to 14 :

```
values.put(Calls.NEW, 0);
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14)
    values.put(Calls.IS_READ, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. My code is not crashing anymore but I still have an issue. In the notification bar from my android phone I still have the missed call icon. Can you tell me how can I solve this?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you about this. I would say that it is another question, you should probably post a new one.

Comment: I posted a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16566314/clear-missed-calls-and-clear-notification-from-android-bar