# clear missed calls and clear notification from android bar

Tags: android, calllog

Using this code I managed to mark all missed calls as read:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(Calls.NEW, 0);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            values.put(Calls.IS_READ, 1);
        }
        StringBuilder where = new StringBuilder();
        where.append(Calls.NEW);
        where.append(" = 1 AND ");
        where.append(Calls.TYPE);
        where.append(" = ?");

        context.getContentResolver().update(Calls.CONTENT_URI, values, where.toString(),
                new String[]{ Integer.toString(Calls.MISSED_TYPE) });
```

but in the android notification bar I still have a flag with missed calls. How can I also clear the notification bar for calls in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I also clear the notification bar for calls in android?

You don't. That `Notification` is put there by another app, and you have no means of controlling whether that `Notification` is displayed, short of building a ROM mod that changes the behavior of that other app.

**UPDATE**: Since this answer was originally written, `NotificationListenerService` was added and can clear notifications, but only on Android 4.3+.

Comment: so there is no way I can clear that? Because it actually looks ugly. YOu read the missed calls and still have the notification in android. Can you give me some suggestions about this?

Comment: @justME: I have no idea why you are clearing the missed calls. You are the one causing the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Your answer seems arrogant. I congratulate your contribution to StackOverflow, but I think you may want to change this. I've shown terrible means of controlling whether that notification is displayed, but it does it, and it partially works for me. That's how I know that I was not causing the problem. I was developing an application for twelve dedicated devices and I wanted each to serve its purpose. Just ME didn't say: "I feel like misusing other peoples devices. Help me".

Answer (score 0):

The only "legal" but extremely ugly and usually useless way to achieve what you want is to show Call Log to user. And I mean literally show (becomes visual, gets focus). In case you want to do this, here's how:

```
public static boolean showCallLog(Context context)
{
    try
    {
        Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
        showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        showCallLog.setType(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
        context.startActivity(showCallLog);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("Couldn't show call log.", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
}
```

The reason behind this mess is the fact that apps authoritatively responsible for call logging and notifying users about missed calls (stock phone apps) use cached values. Why? Because of overall performance. You need to somehow notify those apps that Call Log has changed (seen means changed, as well) and that it should update it. It would be nice if all such apps on all devices would receive a broadcast in order to refresh, but as far as I know, it's not the case.

I hope someone will find a better way (without interrupting the user) to force refresh on stock phone apps.

Comment: There is no requirement that showing the call log must clear any notifications. This may work on some devices, but it may not work on all.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Even though there's no requirement, I haven't seen a device that doesn't, ever. And I've seen many. I suppose there's no other event, in this sort of app, that better suits background check of call log. This solution is terrible enough for it to be used in public apps, so I guess developers could check.