# How to know missed call is-read by user or not?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I want to know if a missed call is read by user or not. I it is read by user then I have to update the content provider. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this links i think this will helps you:

[How to get Missed call & SMS count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621893/how-to-get-missed-call-sms-count)

[how to mask missed calls to read in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561167/how-to-mask-missed-calls-to-read-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html

Comment: It show me the number of missed call but I want to know if a missed call is read by user or not.

Comment: You just need to get Calls.IS_READ by adding "Calls.IS_READ" in projection. If it is 1 then it is read else not.

Comment: If not then I want to update the content provider is not read to read. I to do that?

Comment: replace 
String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };


To 
String[] projection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE,Calls.IS_READ };

Comment: I asked how to update the content provider, not to query the read call.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561167/how-to-mask-missed-calls-to-read-in-android - Check this

Comment: Thank you. It works. Please update your answer then I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
String[] projection = new String[]{CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                CallLog.Calls.DURATION,
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                CallLog.Calls._ID};

String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE+"="+CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE+" AND NEW = 1";                 

Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,projection,where, null, null);      c.moveToFirst();            
Log.d("CALL", ""+c.getCount());         
if(c.getCount() > 0) 
// code that displays the number of missed calls;
```